# Spliting and formatting an array of strings into list items on layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

I have a two-way many to many relationship between `work` and `category` models.  When I pluck the categoies to show on my `work#index`

**HTML:**

```
<% @works.each do |work| %>
   <article class="work-item" data-project="<%= work.id %>">
      <header class="w-article-title ">
         <%=raw work.svg %>
         <h1 class="article-name"><%= work.name %></h1>
         <ul class="categories-total n-visible">
           <li><%= work.categories.pluck(:name) %></li>
         </ul>
       </header>
     </a>
   </article>
<% end %>
```

It ends up returning an array of strings like:

```
["Visual Design", "Strategy + UX", "UxD"]
```

How can I make the layout display:

- indiviual list items?
- Remove the brackets
- trim the "" off the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     <ul class="categories-total n-visible">
       <% work.categories.pluck(:name).each do |n| %>
         <li><%= n %></li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
```

Comment: my god I need to actually read a ruby book.. it so simple.  Thanks so much.  My first ruby/rails/backend project. marking correct asap.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood No problem. Everyone starts somewhere.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, one fruitful study for Ruby is to have a look at all of the methods available for `Array`, `Enumerable`, and `Hash`. These structures are used everywhere, particularly in Rails.